# Error while updating blob data

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to update a picture in the database after selecting it from jFilechooser through the user interface of my application but I keep having the same error : Syntax Error Near ( BULK 'c/:.......',SINGLE_BLOB). here is my code

```
String str = F.getAbsolutePath();
String sql="UPDATE employés  SET photo =
       (SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '"+str+"', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)";
```

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: I guess, you're trying to set `String data` to `blob` field.

Comment: Blob expects a stream of bytes.What you did by mistake is actually can be a good way.Try changing blob to string.Then you may access paths from the DB.

Comment: yeah you 're right, photos are saved as Blob in the Mysql DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code snippet:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE employés SET photo = ?"); // consider to use a WHERE clause for not to update ALL datasets
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(F);
pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, inStream);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
inStream.close();
```

Code similar to official SQL server documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms378813%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx

Comment: Inserting a blob in a database is not database dependent. JDBC defines a number of specific APIs to handle this, and JDBC drivers of databases that have blobs are supposed to implement (most of) them and handle/hide the database specifics.

Comment: @Sam You are welcome. If you want to, you can also mark my answer as accepted or upvote it.